# How to simulate regex lookbehind without regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on a project in C# that is slowly transitioning away from using regex for one reason or another, but so far it's been a pain implementing this.

Specifically, I need to check for unary operators in a mathematical expression, which can be confused with binary operators in just straight string searching.

---

Right now, the project's regex looks something like this:

```
(?<=(?:<<|>>|\+|-|\*|\/|%|&&|\|\||&|\||\^|==|!=|<>|>=|=>|<=|=<|=|<|>)\s*|\A)(?:(?:\+|-|!|~)(?=\w|\())
```

Essentially, it looks behind for binary operators before it assumes the operator is unary.

The current code about to try to replace that regex looks something similar to this:

```
private static readonly string[] _unaryOps = new string[] { "+", "-", "!", "~" };

private string MatchUnaryOp(string expr, int index)
{
    int foundIndex = int.MaxValue; // so currentIndex always starts out less than foundIndex
    string foundOp = null;
    foreach (string op in _unaryOps) {
        int currentIndex = expr.IndexOf(op, index);
        if (currentIndex > -1 && currentIndex < foundIndex) {
            foundIndex = currentIndex;
            foundOp = op;
        }
    }
    return foundOp;
}
```

---

The problem is that this code obviously does not account for the lookbehind, and it ends up incorrectly labeling ambiguous binary operators (+,-) as unary. How can I simulate a lookbehind without regex?

**EDIT:** *If the question seems too broad, I'm only asking for a solution that more properly simulates what the original regex did. As long as it can simulate that specific regex, I'll be able to work with it.*

---

**EDIT 2:**
The above regex currently matches operators like this:

```
5 + -10
    ^ this minus sign matches the conditions in the regex
```

However, the above code currently matches this:

```
5 + -10
  ^ the plus sign is incorrectly assumed to be unary
```

I want to know if there's a viable way to parse that simple expression. Simply determining that the minus is unary, whereas the plus is not. Is there a good way to implement this? Possibly by looping through the binary ops in an array like this?

```
private static readonly string[] _binaryOps = new string[] { "<<", ">>", "+", "-", "*", "/", "%", "&&", "||", "&", "|", "^", "==", "!=", "<>", ">=", "=>", "<=", "=<", "=", "<", ">" };
```

Comment: So essentially the project wants all the flexibility and power of a regular but without the ease of use? Sounds like an interesting project.

Comment: *(I didn't vote)* but I think it's because your question is way to broad as it is now... Also you want/have to switching from a (I hope) working solution to a real nightmare to implement: How would you parse `e = +-+ x++ + ++z;` ?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub The original code threw an exception because it's not valid syntax. The code for handling that sort of parsing is not given in the question because it's really not necessary information. I'm only asking if someone can point me in the right direction to make the above method more accurately simulate the above regex. That's all I need. Nothing more. I can handle the edge cases like the one you mentioned. It's not what I'm asking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about how to write a parser and that is complex but there are many books and tutorials on the topic of parsers.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I'm not asking about writing a complete parser, just a method or two for the above regex.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to provide an example, specify the rules and then give an expected result(s) and show failures. Reading an obtuse regex is a huge task on its own.

Comment: @OmegaMan I edited the question with an example. I just need to parse that simple case correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than reinventing the wheel by creating a parsing engine from scratch it would be better to either rewrite your regular expression to do exactly what you're looking for or provide more details about the algorithm that you're looking to build, complete with more thorough examples.

## Your Expression

`(?<=(?:<<|>>|\+|-|\*|\/|%|&&|\|\||&|\||\^|==|!=|<>|>=|=>|<=|=<|=|<|>)\s*|\A)(?:(?:\+|-|!|~)(?=\w|\())`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Your regular expression could be made more efficient by replacing some of the alternations with character classes, and creating a tree like structure. This would significantly reduce the amount of backtracking the regex engine does.

If the alternation gets to the `\A` then the expression will fail when trying to match `(?:(?:\+|-|!|~)(?=\w|\())`. This is because `\A` denotes the end of the string therefore by definition there can be nothing more after the end.

## Simplified Version

This simplified version does the same thing you're expression does but with less work. Keep in mind the `\A` here would still cause the failed match just like above.

```
(?<=(?:([&|<>=])\1|[-+*\/%&|^=<>]|!=|>=|=[<>]|<[>=])\s*|\A)(?:[-+!~](?=[\w(]))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Holy toledo catfish, can you point me to the tool you used to generate those graffics?

Comment: Hey John, yeah it's from www.debuggex.com. It's pretty neat the image refreshes as you type (assuming it's a valid expression)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. All I did was add another parameter that took the last match or `null` when it's the beginning of the string. It then checked that the match was previously determined to be a binary operator or `null`. If not the method returns.

```
private static readonly string[] _unaryOps = new string[] { "+", "-", "!", "~" };
private static readonly string[] _binaryOps = new string[] { "<<", ">>", "+", "-", "*", "/", "%", "&&", "||", "&", "|", "^", "==", "!=", "<>", ">=", "=>", "<=", "=<", "=", "<", ">" };

private string MatchUnaryOp(string expr, int index, object lastMatch)
{
    if (lastMatch != null && !_binaryOps.Contains(lastMatch.ToString())) {
        return null; // the last match was not a binary operator or the beginning of a string, so this can't be unary.
    }
    int foundIndex = int.MaxValue; // so currentIndex always starts out less than foundIndex
    string foundOp = null;
    foreach (string op in _unaryOps) {
        int currentIndex = expr.IndexOf(op, index);
        if (currentIndex > -1 && currentIndex < foundIndex) {
            foundIndex = currentIndex;
            foundOp = op;
        }
    }
    return foundOp;
}
```